# Import Public Private key pair to a Keystore

Tags: certificates, java, key-generation

I have created a public private key pair using the KeyPairGenerator class in Java. From this key pair I have generated the CSR request using the PKCS10 class which has been sent to a CA for verification. The question is how do I load this public private key pair into a keystore? I cant use KeyStore.SetKeyEntry as it requires a certificate parameter along with the private key.

I thought that I would have to wait for the CA to send back a certificate which should then be used for loading the key pair. But If I create the keystore using the keytool command -

keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -sigalg sha1withRSA -alias aliasname -validity 365 -keystore keystorename

and then load this keystore into the Java keystore class, the keystore object contains a privatekeyentry and a CertificateEntry. How is this possible without obtaining a certificate back from the CA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a public/private key pair with Java code ([`KeyPairGenerator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html)), the key pair normally exists in RAM only. The whole Java cryptography architecture is extensible and it is possible to use a specific `KeyPairGenerator` instance which does saves the private key "somewhere", but, in general, you have to arrange for the saving yourself, e.g. with the [`KeyStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) class or more manually with explicit files (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890313/how-to-use-keystore-in-java-to-store-private-key) for instance).

In any case, the PKCS#10 request sent to the CA contains only the public key; the CA never learns the private key, and therefore cannot send it back to you.

The `keytool` command-line utility can do the storage part itself. In the "keystore" format, private keys don't exist alone but only linked to a certificate, so the `keytool` utility will generate a self-signed certificate accompanying the private key. This is why this command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
```

will ask you a few questions, including a password (to encrypt the private key itself) and some personal things such as your name and country: these ones are for filling the self-signed certificate fields.

When you obtain the certificate from the CA, you can import it in your keystore, *replacing* the self-signed certificate. The "key alias" is used to designate the specific private key you wish to use. See [this blog post](http://kb.kaminskiengineering.com/node/71) for some details on the involved commands.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a keystore with the Java keytool a keypair is generated and the certificate is signed with the private key itself. Therefore you have a self signed certificate in this case.

You can check this with the command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <keystore>
```

The first certificate shown should have the same Owner and Issuer.